# Vue 3 - Composition API - How to use a reusable code from another file in the template?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I created a reusable code in dateTime.js:

```
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default function dateTime() {

    const newDateTimeString = ref(null);

    function showDateTime(data) {
        const dateTime = dayjs(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY') 
        newDateTimeString.value = dateTime;
    }

    return {
        newDateTimeString,
        showDateTime
    }
}
```

**The code from dateTime.js gets called in Table.vue:**

Question: How am I able to get this working? I want to use `{{ showDateTime(scope.row[itemIn.field]) }}` in the template. In my opinion it should trigger eventually the function `showDateTime` inside `dateTime.js`

What I'm doing wrong? Error code: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` which refers to `const { showDateTime } = useDateTime();`

```
<template v-else-if="itemIn.type == 'dateTime'">
    {{ showDateTime(scope.row[itemIn.field]) }}
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useDateTime } from '@/composables/dateTime';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "",
  props: {
    processingData: Object
  },
  components: {
    Flag
  },
  emits: ["unique", "refresh"],

  setup(props, {emit}) {
    
    const { showDateTime } = useDateTime();
    const store = useStore()

    function setStatus(id, route) {
        const object = {
            id: id,
            route: route
        }
        return store.getters.getStatus(object);
    }

    return {
      getScope,
      setUniqueId,
      getClass,
      getWidth,
      navigatePagination,
      setStatus,
      setTag,
      showDateTime
    };
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: The problem is how you use dayjs. `*` import is an object by definition.

Comment: I don't understand. My question is to reuse the function `showDateTime` from the file dateTime.js inside `Table.vue` inside the template itself.

Comment: Then you ask about the wrong thing. You use it correctly but showDateTime will cause an error no matter where you use it for the reason listed above, at least according to what you posted. Also useDateTime is named export but default import, but this would cause a different error, your real code possibly differs, or you reexported it in `@/composables/dateTime`

Answer (score 0):

As you `export default` the `useDateTime` hook, you must import it without the `{ }` :

```
import useDateTime from '@/composables/dateTime';
```